# C# downcast and add to entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

I have the following Classes:

```
class Employee { }

class AdvancedEmployee : Employee { }
```

When I now try to add or edit the Employee, Entity Framework throws an exception:

```
AdvancedEmployee ae=new AdvancedEmployee();
db.Employee.Add(ae as Employee);
```

The exception is:

```
The entity type AdvancedEmployee is not part of the model for the current context.
```

Is it possible to "hard" downcast the object, so that Entity Frameworks accepts the downcasted `AdvancedEmployee`?

Comment: You'd need to create a new instance of `Employee`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because there are a lot of properties in `Employee` and I am lazy, I will use reflection. Thought there was an easier (and maybe faster) solution.

Comment: not sure can you try Employee ae=new AdvancedEmployee() and then db.Employee.Add(ae);

Comment: you should be able to do this : `db.Employee.Add(ae);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to map it. You can try to use AutoMapper or use mine:

```
public static class EntityMapper
{
    public static void Map(object from, object to)
    {
        var properties = to.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => !Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(NotMappedAttribute)));
        foreach (var propertyToMap in properties)
        {
            var value = propertyToMap.GetValue(from);
            propertyToMap.SetValue(to, value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use like this:

```
var baseEmployee = new BaseEmplyee();
Mapper.Map(ae, baseEmployee);
db.Employee.Add(baseEmployee);
```